# Disk Imaging and Recovery Software for Windows XP SP3

Tags: disaster-recovery, disk-image, windows-xp

I have just installed Windows XP SP3 in my workstation and I have a strange behavior in Acronis TrueImage Disk Imaging Software I use. I notices from some forums that there is lot o f posts regarding Acronis TrueImage stability in Windows XP SP3 platform. So I am looking for a stable solution for Disk Imaging to install and use in XP with SP3 installed. Any ideas or assistance is kindly appreciated.

Thank you for assistance 
John.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a backup and restore solution based on disk images?

I have used clonezilla up through windows 7 with reliable success.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a backup and restore solution based on disk images